# Count Number of days in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, date

I have 2 fields fromDate and toDate for a school's term. Say their values are '01-06-2013' to '01-09-2013'. How do I get the total number of days in the term, in vb.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this in vb.net:

```
    Dim t1 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("01-06-2013")
    Dim t2 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("01-09-2013")
    MessageBox.Show(t2.Subtract(t1).Days)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think сlass DateDiff can help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how to do this in .net?

Comment: Sorry, I attach incorrect link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms127413.aspx
There is an example on VB.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (C#):

```
TimeSpan timespan = Convert.ToDateTime("01-09-2013").Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime("01-06-2013")); 
Response.Write(timespan.Days+1);
```

Usually the Subtract method return a value that is one less than the correct value so added one to get excat no of days

OR:

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Day , curDate, srDate) //can replace the first argument with "d"
```

Also check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @Aishvarya Np cheers...also u can use DateDiff (edited the ans)